# Standards for Web Programming

Tags: standards, coding-style, web-standards

This is strictly an opinion/experience question for research purposes.

I was wondering what coding standards companies have in place now for Web Developers? (Document formats, coding standards, file structures, etc.)

Obviously they all can't be listed, but some major ones would give me an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that company coding standards for Web Developers *include* W3C standards, but commercial pressures will tend to encourage whatever solution gets the job done.

I would love to be proved wrong in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The [World Wide Web Consortium](http://www.w3.org/) is the main international standards organization for the World Wide Web.

Comment: I understand that there are standards for the Web Developer community but I would like to know what standards other web developers have to follow on a company level.

Comment: @fjsj Oddly enough, I think there is something wrong with your network connection or your ISP's DNS.

Answer (score 1):

At the previous (large) company I worked for, there were three main standards that were to adhered to for front-end work:

1. All HTML would adhere to the HTML 4.01 Strict standards, with the following exceptions:

   - iframes were to be allowed due to advertising.
   - The `start` attribute was to be allowed within lists.
   - `target="_top"` was allowed to be used for framebreaking purposes.

   These exceptions were codified into a custom doctype document, which is documented [here](http://github.com/NeilCrosby/frontend-test-suite/blob/master/dtd/401_strict_extended.dtd).  All work produced was expected to validate against this doctype.
2. All CSS would validate against the CSS 2.1 standard, with the exception that the * and _ prefix hacks were allowed to be used.
3. All JavaScript was expected to pass through JSLint without issue (strict whitespace was absolutely not turned on).

We also ran regular code reviews with the expectation that these would allow us to pull out the good work done by our developers and codify this into best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI) is something to be considered as well by any serious web developer: http://www.w3.org/WAI/

Answer (score 0):

Try [StyleCI](https://styleci.io), it supports PHP, JavaScript, CSS, Typescript, Less, SCSS and Vue.js.

You can configure StyleCI to your coding standards too and it can automatically fix your code. We use it on a bunch of projects.